# Use existing Sqlite Database in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I have an Android app I wrote that uses a sqllite database, now I am writing the same app for  iPhone. How do I use the existing sqllite database from my android app in the iPhone version?

More specific questions:

- Where do I place the actual sqllite database - What folder?
- Can I just use iPhone sql statements to open and read the data?
- Could I just use an xcode emulator until I move the iPhone app to an actual device?

Answer (score 2):

If you're happy with using sql, you don't necessarily need to go through the CoreData pain barrier. Ray Wenderlich also has a good tutorial on using Sqlite directly in your app here:

[Part 1 - SQLite 101 for iPhone Developers (Intro)](http://www.raywenderlich.com/902/sqlite-101-for-iphone-developers-creating-and-scripting)

[Part 2 - SQLite 101 for iPhone Developers (The actual coding with Sqlite)](http://www.raywenderlich.com/913/sqlite-101-for-iphone-developers-making-our-app)

His site is a great resource for experienced developers wanting a [quick and practical guide to getting started](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials) with almost every aspect of iOS development imaginable.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find a tutorial about how to import a SQLite Databse to core data:

[How To Preload and Import Existing Data](http://www.raywenderlich.com/12170/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data-updated)